# what do execution_date and backfill means in airflow

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I'm new to airflow and I'm trying understand what is `execution_date` means in airflow context. I've read the [tutorial page](https://airflow.apache.org/tutorial.html#id1) from airflow's documentation which states that

> The date specified in this context is an execution_date, which simulates the scheduler running your task or dag at a specific date + time:

I tried to run a task from the tutorial using following command.

```
airflow test tutorial print_date 2015-06-01
```

I expected it to print `execution_date` but the task is printing the actual date on my local system like this.

```
[2018-05-26 20:36:13,880] {bash_operator.py:101} INFO - Sat May 26 20:36:13 IST 2018
```

I thought the scheduler will be simulated at a given time. So I'm confused here understanding about `execution_date` param. Can anyone help me understand this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's printing the current time in your log because it was actually executed at this time.

The execution date is a DAG run parameter. Tasks can use it to have a date reference different from when the task will actually be executed.

Example: say you're interested in storing currency rates once per day. You want to get rates since 2010. You'll have a task in your DAG to call an API which will return the currency rate for a day. You can create a DAG with a start date of 2010-01-01 with a schedule of once per day. Even if you create it now, in 2018, it will run for every day since the start date and thanks to the execution date you'll have the correct data.

Comment: So it is just a runtime argument passed to DAG which can be used by tasks defined in it, right?

Comment: Yes. But it also defines how often your DAG will run when you combine it with the schedule